# Spring Boot - NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/classic/Level

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I created a vanilla Spring Boot App (`1.5.9.RELEASE`) but when I `Run As -> Spring Boot App` (in Eclipse Oxygen) I get

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/classic/Level
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.<clinit>(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem.get(LoggingSystem.java:170)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem.get(LoggingSystem.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:229)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:209)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:292)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at demo.spring.boot.app.CourseApiApp.main(CourseApiApp.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.classic.Level
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 19 more
```

***pom.xml***

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>demo.spring.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>boot-demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

***App***

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CourseApiApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SpringApplication.run(CourseApiApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

***Remark***

I also tried `mvn clean package` -> `java -jar target/boot-demo.jar` which gives me

```
Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/classic/LoggerContext
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:59)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:50)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:273)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:179)
    at demo.spring.boot.app.CourseApiApp.main(CourseApiApp.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:370)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52)
    at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Resource.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:462)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    ... 25 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/classic/LoggerContext
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:59)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:50)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:273)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:179)
    at demo.spring.boot.app.CourseApiApp.main(CourseApiApp.java:11)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:370)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52)
    at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Resource.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:462)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: I think you have 2 problem : first it seems you have a ZipException, it's thrown when Spring is trying to read a jar file. Then you don't have any `slf4` implementation in your classpath, you can add `logback` so the first exception will be successfully logged

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Extending Mark Bramnik answer, It does look like you don't have logback, which is pretty weird because `spring-boot-starter-web` have a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-logging`. Just try to add `spring-boot-starter-logging` to your POM file

Comment: error still occurs after adding `spring-boot-starter-logging`

Comment: I think the original problem is a `java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths`. Do you have a broken jar file in you classpath ?

Comment: to find that out I probably have to wipe out my .m2?

Comment: yes otherwise you can clean maven repo with this command `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`

Comment: wiping out just the 'ch' folder in .m2 did it for me. Thanks

Comment: thanks, just add this in a POM and it works. thanks, Guy.

`       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency> `

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to use a logback logging implementation but don't have a logback jar in the classpath:

Please try adding something like this (depending on Spring Boot version there can be another actual version of logback dependency)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you'll probably want to configure loggers, appenders and so forth. For more information about logging in spring boot read [a chapter from official Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html).

Comment: `logback-classic` already appears in maven dependencies. A look into the dependency hierarchy shows that `logback-classic` and `logback-core` are imported via the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency (1.5.9.RELEASE)... weird stuff...

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, though not very intelligent: Deleted the ch folder from within .m2 folder, and did a Run > 'Maven install' from Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I had a broken jar in the classpath, after removing everything from .m2 and updating it worked.

Comment: How do you know its a broken JAR ?

Comment: Sometimes maven spews out a (one line) error message warning of zero size jars.  I guess sometimes it might be corruption: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service/issues/51 ?

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot application is expecting logback classic dependency.Since its unable to find the logback-classic jar in classpath its throwing an error
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/classic/turbo/TurboFilter.

After adding the below dependency application started without any issues.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing everything from maven repo and updating project in eclipse worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${logback.version}</version> -->
    </dependency>
```

Adding this logback explicitly, solved the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting ch  folder in .m2 directory and update maven project in eclipse project helps me in fixing this issue.

Comment: what is the ch folder?  Did you mean repository folder?

Answer (score 0):

For us `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator` meant "I had excluded spring-boot-starter-logging but needed to add `spring-boot-starter-log4j2`" or something like that, apparently.

working pom:

```
<build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId></dependency>

  <dependency>
     ...something internal
         <exclusions>
        <exclusion><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId></exclusion>
      </exclusions>
```

According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/howto-logging.html if you want to use log4j instead of logback you're supposed to "exclude" spring-boot-starter-logging so I guess the pattern of having to reject it from every dependency apps isn't too far off.  Kind of weird though...

So maybe what happened was if you "just exclude"  Maybe they were still bringing in "just logback" (without joran) as a separate dependency, which confused spring boot?

Comment: Could you share the pom file

Comment: As requested...

Comment: I have resolved the issue already but thanks. For me it was about building all the dependent project and cleaning the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Got error "NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/classic/Level":
Add following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```